# Should I use a regexp or a top-down LL(1) parser in the following case?

Tags: java, parsing, lexer

I need to parse a flightplan document in order to extract relevant information. A sample document is given below:

```
(FPL-REU974-IS
-B77L/H-SDE1E2E3GFHIJ4J5M1RWXYZ/LB1D1
-LFPG1845
-N0490F310 OKASI UL612 MILPA UM730 TOP UL50 ELB UL12 VELAD UM728 NERAR UP3
RCA/N0489F350 UR611 TIKAT UG300 MAV UM665G ITLOX UM665 UVESO/N0486F370 DCT DENLI
UR780 MIDRI UR780G UVENA
-FMEE1036 FIMP
-PBN/A1D1L1S1 NAV/RNP10 DOF/121114 REG/FOLRA EET/LSAS0039 LFFF0039 LIMM0048 LIRR0111
LMMM0218 HLLL0237 HECC0343 HSSS0425 HAAA0545 HKNA0700 HCSM0701 FSSS0745 FMMM0900
SEL/CGFR ORGN/RUKOUU PER/C SRC/RQP RMK/ADSB ACARS EQUIPPED TCAS EQUIPPED)
```

As illustrated above. The flightplan information is contained between `(` and `)`. The first line contains the `FPL` "keyword", aircraft identification (REU974) and type of flight(IS) (`-` is used as as seperator)

The following lines contain additional information about the flight such as departure airport and time (line 3, LFPG1845), a list of wayoipoints (line 4), arrival aiport and time (line 5) and so forth.

I was considering two approaches to parsing this data:

- Use regular expressions to extract the relevant information from the document.
- Write a top-down LL(1) recursive descent lexer and parser, and consider the flightplan document as a "DSL" of sorts.

In the latter case, I would write a lexer, which would return tokens such as `(`, `-`, `/`,`\n`,`number`,`word`. These tokens would in turn be consummed by a parser in order to extract the relevant information from the flightplan. The parser would also validate the input. For example, in the first line, the aircraft identification can be no more than 7 characters long, and the type of flight can only contain characters from a given set.

Would the previous approach be overkill compared to using regular expressions?

Also what would be the most efficient approach, considering that I need to parse thousands of flightplans, and I need to make this fast.

*Edit*: The implementation language would be Java

Comment: The implementation would be in Java

Comment: I would definitely go with regexp. your data is not nested/recursive for writing a parser for it. writing a lexer is more appropriate for nested data like  mathematical equation or parse a programming language.

Comment: And what about validation? How can you make sure that the fpl document is valid with a regexp?

Comment: each regex will be inside an if statement. if succeeded make your validation test and continue to next line(and next validation). in case any validation failed, ignore current flightplan doc, and move to next one. if you could add your specification i can give it a coding try

Comment: OK I get your point. So if I understand correctly, a LL(1) Parser/Lexer should be used when the language contains a highly-recursive structure. Here is a link to a flightplan specification: https://files.eurofpl.eu/originalfpl/pdfs/EuroFPL-ICAO_Flightplan_Form_Basics-latest.pdf. If you give me some boiler-plate code to get started, I will accept your answer

Comment: Pls add  to you question the output you expect from the given flighplan

Comment: 'Highly' has nothing to do  with it. If recursive syntax is present *at all*, you must use a parser, not a scanner.

Comment: @YyYo Wrtitng a *parser* is more appropriate for nested data like ...